# C++ Encryption Program Not Working

Tags: c++, encryption

I have been writing a very basic encryption program in C++ where the user is asked to enter a message, and then a number with the same number of digits as the number of characters in the message. Then it converts each character in the message to the ascii number, and then adds the each digit in the number to the ascii, and then converts back to a character and returns the encrypted string. And the progress happens in reverse to decrypt. When I tried to encrypt "hello", I got �����. Can someone please explain how I can fix this? I have not finished the code, but this is it so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string encryptMsg(string msg)
{
    cout << "Enter a number that is " << msg.length() << " digits long: ";
    string codekey;
    cin >> codekey;
    char msgArr[msg.length()];
    int keyCode[msg.length()];
    int tempcount = 0;
    for(char& c : msg) {
        msgArr[tempcount] = c;
        tempcount++;
    };
    tempcount = 0;

    for(char& c : codekey) {
        keyCode[tempcount] = c;
        tempcount++;
    };
    double tempascii;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(msgArr)/sizeof(msgArr[0])); i++)
    {
        tempascii = msgArr[i];
        tempascii = tempascii + keyCode[i];
        msgArr[i] = tempascii;
    };
    string outmsg;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(msgArr)/sizeof(msgArr[0])); i++)
    {
        outmsg = outmsg + msgArr[i];
    };
    return outmsg;
}

string decryptMsg(string msg)
{
    char msgArr[msg.length()];
    int tempcount = 0;
    for(char& c : msg) {
        msgArr[tempcount] = c;
        tempcount++;
    };
    double tempascii;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(msgArr)/sizeof(msgArr[0])); i++)
    {
        tempascii = msgArr[i];
        tempascii = tempascii - 3;
        msgArr[i] = tempascii;
    };
    string outmsg;
    for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(msgArr)/sizeof(msgArr[0])); i++)
    {
        outmsg = outmsg + msgArr[i];
    };
    return outmsg;
};

int main()
{
    string mode;
    string msg;
    cout << "Encryption Program" << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to encrypt or decrypt?" << endl;
    cin >> mode;
    if (mode == "encrypt" || mode == "Encrypt" || mode == "ENCRYPT" || mode == "1")
    {
        cout << "Encryption. ENTER MSG HERE: ";
        cin >> msg;
        cout << encryptMsg(msg);
    } else if (mode =="decrypt" || mode == "Decrypt" || mode == "DECRYPT" || mode == "2")
    {
        cout << "Decryption. ENTER MSG HERE: ";
        cin >> msg;
        cout << decryptMsg(msg);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `char msgArr[msg.length()];` -- This line and the one right after it are both invalid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of entries denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value such as a variable or the result of a runtime function call.  Use `std::vector<char> msgArr(msg.length())` instead.  Since those are not really arrays, I have no idea the result of doing things like this: `sizeof(msgArr)/sizeof(msgArr[0])`. With `vector`, you just use the `size()` function.

Comment: Also, you could have cut down your `main` function by just doing a direct call to encrypt or decrypt functions with known data, instead of posting all of that input/output code.

Comment: There's a lot of style issues with the code that I shall skip for now, but in `keyCode[tempcount] = c;` - do you mean `keyCode[tempcount] = c - '0';`? If the user types `9`, do you wish to add `57` or `9`?

Comment: You probably don't want to do the operations on the ASCII values, since you might end up with stuff like control characters. Instead, assign an integer value to each of the possible characters that might appear in the message.

Comment: Also, variable length arrays like `char msgArr[msg.length()];` aren't standard features, so it's a good idea not to use them, especially when you're also using `sizeof()`, which as far as I know is compile-time constant. I don't know why you're converting the strings into char arrays in the first place since you can just use the subscript operator (`[]`) on strings just like char arrays.

Comment: @FeiXiang That sounds like a very good idea and I will try it as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you, this fixed my problem, but I don't understand how. Why does it result in 57 if I type 9?

Comment: The ASCII code for '9' is 57, as you read in the digits as a string in `codekey`. You can see this by doing `std::cout << (int) '9' << '\n';`

Comment: @BeckettO'Brien visit [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and all will be clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you. I understand now. I am not experienced with ASCII, and I am still confused why when I encrypt, I increase a value by 1, but the result is not as it would be on the ASCII table.

Comment: You had a number of problems in your code that were giving you grief. I put together an answer below to help you sort them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of potential problems reading data with `cin`. If any of your input contains whitespace (intentional or unintentional), your code breaks. (they same occurs if you use a type that doesn't consume leading whitespace, such as `char`) Better to use *line-oriented* input such as `getline` to read user input to insure your `'\n'` generated by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is read and discarded.

Your code lacks any meaningful validation. You must validate all user input to insure there were no stream errors encountered, the user didn't cancel input by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> on windows -- but see: [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/))

Further, if you are reading digits into a string you will rely on for encryption, you need to validate that each character read into `codekey` was in fact a digit. (the functions in `<cctype>`, like `isdigit()` can help).

As explained in the comments `char msgArr[msg.length()];` is wrong. The C++ standard does not include Variable Length Arrays (VLA's) like the C standard does. gcc offers VLA's as an extension to the standard but that makes your code non-portable.

If you simply want to encrypt the characters in `msg` in-place, there is no need for any other string or storage in `encryptMsg` -- just add your digit to the character in `msg` in place. For example, you could do something as simple as the following to encrypt `msg` in-place:

```
string encryptMsg(string& msg)
{
    string codekey;             /* string codekey, result */
    const char *k;              /* pointer to chars in codekey */

    cout << "Enter a number that is " << msg.length() << " digits long: ";
    if (!getline (cin, codekey)) {          /* read codekey */
        cerr << "error: invalid input - codekey\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (codekey.length() < msg.length()) {  /* validate codekey length */
        cerr << "error: insufficient number of digits entered.\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    k = codekey.c_str();        /* initialize k to 1st char in codekey */
    for (char& c : msg) {       /* loop over each char in msg */
        if (!isdigit(*k)) {     /* validate char is a digit */
            cerr << "error: non-numeric input '" << *k << "'\n";
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        c = c + (*k++ - '0');   /* add digit val to c, encrypting msg */
    }
    return msg;                 /* return encrypted result */
}
```

To preserve `msg`, you can simply declare `outmsg` as a `string` as well and assign `outmsg = msg;` and then encrypt the characters in `outmsg` with the digits entered in `codekey`, e.g.

```
string encryptMsg(string& msg)
{
    string codekey, outmsg = msg;   /* string codekey, outmsg */
    const char *k;                  /* pointer to chars in codekey */

    cout << "Enter a number that is " << msg.length() << " digits long: ";
    if (!getline (cin, codekey)) {          /* read codekey */
        cerr << "error: invalid input - codekey\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (codekey.length() < msg.length()) {  /* validate codekey length */
        cerr << "error: insufficient number of digits entered.\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    k = codekey.c_str();        /* initialize k to 1st char in codekey */
    for (char& c : outmsg) {    /* loop over each char in msg */
        if (!isdigit(*k)) {     /* validate char is a digit */
            cerr << "error: non-numeric input '" << *k << "'\n";
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        c += (*k++ - '0');   /* add digit val to c, encrypting msg */
    }
    return outmsg;           /* return encrypted outmsg */
}
```

Otherwise, C++ provides for simple allocation with `new` and `delete`, or you can simply use a `string` for `codekey` -- but then you will need an iterator to help iterate over the characters in `codekey` while simultaneously iterating over the characters in `msg`. It's up to you, but in these cases I find a simple allocation for the resulting message and using a simple character pointer to fill the encrypted string before assigning to a `string` to return is about as easy as anything else, e.g.

```
string encryptMsg(string& msg)
{
    char *tmp = new char[msg.length() + 1], /* allocate for length + 1 */
        *p = tmp;                           /* pointer to tmp */
    const char *k;                          /* pointer to use for key */
    string codekey, res;                    /* string codekey, result */

    cout << "Enter a number that is " << msg.length() << " digits long: ";
    if (!getline (cin, codekey)) {          /* read codekey */
        cerr << "error: invalid input - codekey\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (codekey.length() < msg.length()) {  /* validate codekey length */
        cerr << "error: insufficient number of digits entered.\n";
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    k = codekey.c_str();        /* initialize k to 1st char in codekey */
    for (char& c : msg) {       /* loop over each char in msg */
        if (!isdigit(*k)) {     /* validate char is a digit */
            cerr << "error: non-numeric input '" << *k << "'\n";
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *p++ = c + (*k++ - '0');    /* add digit val to c, store in tmp */
    }
    *p = 0;         /* nul-termiante tmp */
    res = tmp;      /* assign char array to string res */
    delete[] tmp;   /* free allocated memory */
    return res;     /* return encrypted result */
}
```

You can put a short example program together to validate the encrypt to insure it is doing what you intend it to do. Below, we enter `"hello"` as `msg`, encrypt and use `"11111"` as `codekey` to get the intended `"ifmmp"` returned by `encryptMsg`, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

string encryptMsg(string& msg)
{ ... }

int main (void) {

    string mode, msg;

    cout << "mode: ";
    if (!getline (cin, mode)) { /* read mode (discarding trailing '\n') */
        cerr << "error: invalid input - mode\n";
        return 1;
    }
    for (char& c : mode)        /* convert mode to lowercase */
        c = tolower(c);
    if (mode == "encrypt" || mode == "1") { /* check mode */
        cout << "msg : ";           /* prompt for msg */
        if (!getline (cin, msg)) {  /* read msg */
            cerr << "error: invalid input - msg\n";
            return 1;
        }
        /* output encrypted result */
        cout << "res : " << encryptMsg(msg) << '\n';
    }
}
```

(**note:** all functions generate the same output, but in the final two `msg` is preserved unchanged)

**Compile With Warnings Enabled**

For all code you compile, you want to compile with *Warnings Enabled*, for gcc/g++ and clang, you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for a fairly inclusive set of warnings, clang also offers `-Weverything`. VS (`cl.exe`) uses `/W#` where `#` is `1-4`, it also offers `/Wall` (which really means all), and you can disable specific warnings you don't want reported with `/w####` where `####` is the code for the warning to disable. Do not accept code until it compiles without warning.

Read an understand any warnings you get, they point out specific problems and the line on which the problem can be found. (g++ goes a bit overboard in producing a plethora of messages, but still, they identify the problem and line). You can learn a lot by listening what your compiler is trying to tell you.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/asciiencrypt3
mode: EnCRypt
msg : hello
Enter a number that is 5 digits long: 11111
res : ifmmp
```

Since this looks a lot like an assignment, you can tackle the remainder of the implementation from here. If you run into problems, add your updated code *below your existing question*, and I'm happy to help further.

Comment: Thanks you! This helped a lot. I still have to add in safety for if they enter a number that does not correspond to anything on the ASCII chart, but I want to thank you for working with me even though I am very bad at c++

Comment: When everybody starts learning c++, they are all very bad at it. It's supposed to feel difficult, just as learning anything worthwhile feels when you first start. Don't worry, if you work at it, and focus on learning to do it right -- not just making it work, you will be a wizard in no time. (well, a reasonable amount of time...)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but if I may: do you know of any good online c or c++ courses?

Comment: [Definitive C++ Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and always keep [C++ language](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language) handy, and while not flawless, working through the [cplusplus tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) you will have a good primer for the basics.